# Custom Color with cgColor

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicolor, cgcolor

It might be the stupidest question you saw all day but i couldn't find a solution. i have a rounded image view with borders and i want the borders to be the the same blue as the default tint color in Xcode so if you could help that would be great . and sorry for the noonish question ;)

**Now i have this:**

```
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
```

and i need to change

```
UIColor.gray.cgColor
```

to be the **same** blue as the default tint color without causing a crash or an error ... how can it be done?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create the new color with blue color properties  and apply to imageView

```
let color = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0)
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
```

alertnatively you can use tintColor property of imageView like

```
imageView.layer.borderColor = imageView.tintColor.cgColor
```

Answer (score 2):

Just drag and drop whatever color you want such as: 
[image]

Comment: i tried that but there is an error saying :  `Cannot assign value of type 'UIColor' to type 'CGColor?'`

Comment: just use imageView.borderColor  =